# Java_While loop- array items' index positions

Tags: arrays

I have some problems with  the following code fragment where I should determine the final contents of the array:

As it is obvious that left starts with 1 becomes 2  and  right starts with 4 becomes 3 in the mechanism of the loop;

As far as I know, the array items allocate these values temporarily in the memory heap and the index of items have changed during the while loop;

Could you please explain me, what happens to the numbers[right] and  numbers[ ] after the assignment? Are they shifting or changing place?

I am a bit confused.

Thanks,

## Serb

```
int [] numbers = {55,22,99,67,75,100}; 
int left = 1;
int right = numbers.length - 2;             


while (left <= right)       
    {
             numbers[]right = numbers[]left;         
             left ++;    
             right --;    
            }
```

========================

Comment: Either you typed this badly, or your original code could not compile. What error does `numbers[]right = numbers[]left` give?

Comment: I had made a typo in made code. So sorry for that. It should have been numbers[right] = numbers[left];

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a typo in your code, it should be numbers[right] = numbers[left];
After execution of this code the array numbers[] will be {55,22,99,99,22,100}. You are right about the mechanism of the loop. Left index is being increased until it is equal to right index. The right index is being decreased. You copy array element from left index to right index.

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry I had made a typo in my code.Yesterday I discussed with my tutor also. I understood the issue.

Comment: I had made a typo in made code. So sorry for that. It should have been numbers[right] = numbers[left]; Yesterday I discussed with my tutor as well. I understood that just the values of the index elements are  updated. There is no shifting in the array elements.  Thanks so much for the comment